# Hide top and bottom toolbars when using CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, mobile, android-coordinatorlayout

I have managed to figure out how to add a bottom toolbar to `CoordinatorLayout`, but can't seem to figure out how to hide the bottom `RelativeLayout`.

If I add `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` to the bottom `RelativeLayout`, the bottom bar appears when the user scroll upwards. The desired effect is **both top and bottom bars** appear when the user scrolls upwards. Any ideas how I would approach this? A universal bottom bar (for simple actions) across all the tab is needed since my `ViewPager` contain complicated code from other libraries.

A floating action button is not preferable since it hides the collection of actions inside a button that requires the user to tap and expand. Here below is my xml layout for managing the tabs and pager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#1378BB"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:background="#3202c4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any thoughts or ideas? I tried placing the toolbar inside CollapsingToolbarLayout and use `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, but that only anchored the toolbar to `AppBarLayout` and not the entire `CoordinatorLayout`

Only if I could get `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` to trigger the other way around for the bottom `RelativeLayout` (make bar appear when scrolling in the *opposite direction* it was intended to trigger)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add custom `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` to the bottom `Toolbar`. `Toolbar` must be a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`.

Mark it with:

```
app:layout_behavior="{name_of_the_class_of_behavior}"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

In custom behaviour override to methods:

```
@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View fab, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
}
```

and the second one is:

```
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View fab, View dependency)
```

where you control the visibility of the target view. Basically what is needed is to measure what part of `AppBarLayout` is shown, translate it and set it to your view accordingly:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
int viewBottomMargin = lp.bottomMargin;
int distanceToScroll = view.getHeight() + viewBottomMargin;
float ratio = dependency.getY() / toolbarHeight;
view.setTranslationY(-distanceToScroll * ratio);
```

More about it [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/customizing-coordinatorlayouts-behavior/)